# Intelli J IDEA Artifacts,Post-processing is not working

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, ant

After the artifact is built,I want to run a ant target.But it was not working.

**1.I created an ant target by Ant Build Tool Window. (it could run independently)**

[image]

**2.I selected the Run Ant target checkbox and specify the target.**

[image]

**3.it showed me none aftering setting.**

[image]

When I run Build-->Build artifacts,the ant target did not work.
But When I just run it by Ant Build Tool,it worked well.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Make you sure you have defined your **target** in your **build.xml** file.

Below is an example build XML.

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name = "Hello World Project" default = "info">
    <target name = "info">
        <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

When you add the XML file to IntelliJ IDEA, you can find targets listed under your project

[image: Target displayed within IntelliJ IDEA]

You can then add the target to pre-processing or post-processing tasks.

[image: Browse window for selecting targets]
[image: Post processing target]